# How to access EISA Configuration

Tags: windows, partitioning

I would like to find out how to activate the backup software, stored on the (EISA Configuration) of my Vaio PCG-GRT300Z laptop.

The disk layout below shows that I have a  EISA Configuration but can’t  get to that partition.

```
100 GB
98.16 GB                total disk space
6.01 GB NTFS    (EISA Configuration)    Software shipped with Lap Top
C:  45.83 GB NTFS               System Disk
D:  41.32 GB NTFS               Storage Disk
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing F10 key when your laptop starts. That will take you to VAIO Recovery Wizard, which is located on the partition you are trying to access. Also, I was wondering if the model no. of your laptop (PCG-GRT300Z) is correct. I couldn't find it on Sony web-site. :)